# How to translate English to Chinese in php for windows

Tags: php, windows, internationalization, xampp, gettext

I wanted to translate my whole php web page from English to Chinese, similar as WordPress Translation. Is there any better way or suitable library that able to do this so that it will work on Windows and also Chinese Windows version?

I have tried using gettext PHP internationalization but it does not work on my Windows.

```
//messages.po
<?php
$language = "zh_CN";
putenv("LC_ALL=$language");

$domain = "messages";
bindtextdomain($domain, "Local"); 
bind_textdomain_codeset($domain, 'UTF-8');
textdomain($domain);
echo _("HELLO_WORLD");
?>
```

- PHP version 5.6.12
- Windows 8.1 Single Language
- Windows 10 Pro

Comment: have you tried changing locale of windows OS? and then checking it?

Comment: yup, I have tired, but still not working. Do you know any alternative way except for gettext?